# How do I declare a namespace so Typescript adds it to the window object and not a local variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get Typescript to declare my namespace globally. Give the following Typescript

```
declare namespace myNameSpace { export function config(): () => any };

namespace myNameSpace {
    export function config(config: any) {  }
};
```

This is the output

```
;
var myNameSpace;
(function (myNameSpace) {
    function config(config) { }
    myNameSpace.config = config;
})(myNameSpace || (myNameSpace = {}));
;
```

But what I really can't figure out is how to make the

`(myNameSpace || (myNameSpace = {}))`

into

`(window['myNameSpace'] || (window['myNameSpace'] = {}))`

Comment: Why do you need that? by default they are the same when your code is executed on the browser.

Comment: The 'myNameSpace' variable in the output is _not_ a local variable, but is indeed already global, attached to 'window' implicitly. There's no need to explicitly prefix 'myNameSpace with 'window'.